Manga whose main character finds a beast that starts following him
The MC was living in a village with his family and he ends up finding a beast that follows him. He is trained in magic and one of his family members works as a mage for the king—he will find that out later though. Some people try to kill his family to take his beast. Eventually his village comes under attack by monsters and retreat to a fort that end up with everyone dying except him. He kills the monster and falls into a river. Everyone thinks the MC is dead.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?   Was it in colour or black-and-white?

I read it on an app but the app closed down here in the u.s.  it was also on manga fire. The manga was in black and white.

what kind of beast is it? wolf? dragon? carbuncle? pokemon? etc
